# Swift leave a row selected after changing viewcontroller

Tags: swift, row, tableview

i have a two view application. If i select a row a segue load the second view Controller. I want that when i return back to my first controller the row is is still selected. I have tried with this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!


   self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)

}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)


}
```

but when returning back the row not remain selected. What's is the problem??
P.S.: I want no multiple selection, only one row at time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a UITableViewController subclass as your source view controller, what I presume because you are overriding the table view delegate methods, you can use the flag `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` on your view controller to get this behavior.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
}
```

Or you can set this in your Storyboard as well, when selecting the attributes selector of your source table view controller, you have to *untick* the Clear on Appearance checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Hi not working! if i use self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true row don't stay selected when i move to another controller...   How can i leave a row selected until another cell is selected??

Comment: Hello. I corrected my answer. I misread your question in the first place and presumed you want to deselect the cell on return. Please find the corrected version above.